# PHP APC Filter out large PDF files

Tags: php, caching, apc

There is not too much information in the PHP APC documentation about filtering files.

"A comma-separated list of POSIX extended regular expressions. If any pattern matches the source filename, the file will not be cached. Note that the filename used for matching is the one passed to include/require, not the absolute path. If the first character of the expression is a + then the expression will be additive in the sense that any files matched by the expression will be cached, and if the first character is a - then anything matched will not be cached. The - case is the default, so it can be left off."
http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.filters

I am looking to prevent APC for caching large PDF files. How can I do that using the apc.filter setting.

Many thanks.

Comment: APC is opcode cacher. Are you sure APC is trying to cache (not existing) opcode of PDF-file?

Comment: Are your PDFs being generated by a PHP script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APC only caches files that are being run through the PHP interpreter. If this is happening for PDF files at all, your server is misconfigured, and you need to fix that.

Ordinarily, PDF files (like any other static media) should be getting served up directly by Apache -- neither PHP nor APC would ever even look at them.